# What happened to PFObject equality in latest parse ios SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

In Version 1.8.5 of parse SDK I was able to compare PFObjects using ==. For example if I wanted to compare the createBy property of a PFObject to my current user I would do something like this:

```
if somePFObject["createdBy"] as? PFUser == PFUser.currentUser() {
   //do some stuff
}
```

But now I am using 1.13.0 and noticing that even though both of the PFUser Objects contain the same fields and values they are not returning true when testing for equality. What's changed? I'm seeing this in many other places in my project where I am comparing PFObjects using == or even when using PFObjects as hash keys.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fortunately there is objectID that will work fine

```
let dude = somePFObject["createdBy"] as? PFUser
if dude.objectID! == PFUser.currentUser().objectID! {
   //do some stuff
}
```